# JS or JQuery DIV fixed menu height for body padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I belive my doubt is quite simple, but I'm not achieving the result I need.
I'm using BS4 to build a website.

I have a fixed-top navbar, using the class "fixed-top", but I don't know its actual height, and as the responsive goes on, it changes.

I want to calculate the height of the navbar via JQuery or JS then add the same height as PADDING-TOP on body, so it will be always aligned correctly.

It must happen on window load and resize.

What would be the correct way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: @Hooman I have the padding correctly set on all my breakpoints, this is a "just in case" alternative for devices which zoom can be applied and distort the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$element.outerHeight()` includes the vertical padding and borders in the height calculation.

`$element.height()` is the raw height of the element.

```
$(window).on("load resize", function (event) {
    var $navbar = $(".my-navbar");
    var $body = $("body");

    $body.css("padding-top", $navbar.outerHeight());
});
```

Comment: It worked very well, Lars. Much more simples than I was trying to do here. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('body').css("padding-top", $(".fixed-top").height());
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/height/